# RequestError(400, 'parse_exception', 'unknown key [properties] for create index')

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create an elasticsearch index with python whose content is a series of coordinates to later visualize this data in a kibana map.

Unfortunately I am getting this error message:

```
RequestError(400, 'parse_exception', 'unknown key [properties] for create index')
```

This is the code I am using:

```py
es = Elasticsearch()

mappings = {
       "properties": {
            "geo": {
                "properties": {
                     "location": {
                         "type": "geo_point"
                 }
            }
        }
     } 
 }
 
es.indices.create(index='geodata', body=mappings)
es_entries['geo']={ 'location': str(coor[0])+","+str(coor[1])}
es.index(index='geodata', doc_type="doc", body=es_entries)
```

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great job so far, you're almost there. There are a few changes to make:

```
    mappings = {
       "mappings": {                      <--- add this
           "properties": {
                "geo": {
                    "properties": {
                         "location": {
                             "type": "geo_point"
                         }
                     }
                }
            }
         }
     }
     
    es.indices.create(index='geodata', body=mappings)
    es_entries['geo']={ 'location': str(coor[0])+","+str(coor[1])}
    es.index(index='geodata', doc_type="_doc", body=es_entries)    
                                        ^
                                        |
                                   modify this
```